# TcpListener hanging after reading all bytes

Tags: c#, .net, tcp

I'm trying to use the `TcpListener` to listen to some data.

I'm sending this request (from Fiddler):

```
GET http://localhost:10000/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:10000
```

The listener is here:

```cs
internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int PORT = 10000;
        var ipAddressParts = new byte[] {127, 0, 0, 1};
        var ipAddress = new IPAddress(ipAddressParts);
        var server = new TcpListener(ipAddress, PORT);

        const int BUFFER_SIZE = 256;
        Console.WriteLine($"Starting on {ipAddress}:{PORT}.");
        server.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            var client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Client accepted");

            var stream = client.GetStream();

            var readCount = default(int);
            var data = new List<byte[]>();

            do
            {
                var buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

                readCount = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);  // Read hanging here.
                Console.WriteLine($"Received {readCount} bytes.");
                if (readCount != 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ASCII.GetString(buffer));
                }

                data.Add(buffer);
            } while (readCount != 0);

            var message = ASCII.GetBytes($"{DateTime.Now:D} Hello World!!!");
            stream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The listener works as expected and received and prints the message, outputting:

```
Starting on 127.0.0.1:10000.
Client accepted
Received 62 bytes.
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:10000
```

However, it then hangs on the next read operation in the next loop.  I understand that there's no more data to read, so I expected it to return zero for the bytes read and then exit the loop.

The [MSDN Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) implied that this is the correct way to use this.

What condition should I be using to check for the end of the read?

Comment: The Read() call will wait for additional data if none is available. It will return 0 when the connection is closed. Since it doesn't reach your Write() code, Fiddler is hanging waiting for the response. You will need to detect the end of the HTTP request yourself to determine when to write a response. I believe HTTP uses two consecutive newlines (\r\n\r\n) to indicate the end of the headers in a request.

Comment: Also, if you check for the \r\n\r\n manually - keep in mind that they may be split across separate buffers (from separate Read() calls)

Comment: @Wiz The problem isn't spotting the end of the HTTP headers, it's spotting when all TCP data has been received.  This just happens to be HTTP, could be any TCP protocol though.

Comment: Then, I think it depends more on the transfer protocol itself. Some protocols include a header of some sort that will indicate the length of data to expect. Others may close the connection at the end of the data (causing Read to return 0). And others may write a special sequence of bytes at the end of the data. In your sample case, I think HTTP waits for a response before closing the connection. While the connection remains 'open' there is no way to know the sender has finished transferring all of the data unless they follow one of the methods above. (Please correct me if I forgot anything)

Comment: @Wiz I think you're misunderstanding the problem.  The protocol I'm interested in is TCP.  HTTP is just convenience.

Comment: I feel like I'm understanding, but maybe not explaining it well enough.  In case it helps - From Stream.Read()  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.read  The implementation will block until at least one byte of data can be read, in the event that no data is available. Read returns 0 only when there is no more data in the stream and no more is expected (such as a closed socket or end of file).

Comment: There is no generic way to say 'this is the end of the data' with TCP connections. It relies heavily on whether the sender closes the connection and the contents of the data itself.

Answer (score 0):

In your do-while loop check, use the DataAvailable attribute instead of your own readCount. Documentation can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.dataavailable?view=netframework-4.8
This would look something like:

`do {
...
} while (stream.DataAvailable);`

Comment: I'd be curious what the result of this is when there is a delay between network transmissions. For example if you read all the available data, and check DataAvailable before the next data is transferred - would it cause the application to think it completed when additional data was still inbound. My understanding from reading the documentation is that it would not be reliable to check for the end of the data. It only says if this is True, the Read() call returns immediately. This may not necessarily mean that there won't be data available 2 seconds later.

Comment: @Wiz The definition of the `Read()` method is that it will only return `0` if there is no more data to read.

Comment: From NetworkStream.Read() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read states: This method reads data into the buffer parameter and returns the number of bytes successfully read. If the socket is closed, the Read method returns 0. The Read operation reads as much data as is available, up to the number of bytes specified by the size parameter. If the remote host shuts down the connection, and all available data has been received, the Read method completes immediately and return zero bytes.

Comment: Based on this (and my experience with it) I believe it only returns 0 when the connection is closed. Logically there is no way to know there is no more data coming unless the sender closes the connection or you manually determine it based on the data received. For example if the client sends 5 bytes, then waits 10 seconds and sends 5 more bytes - how would the server know to wait for more data after the first 5 bytes?

Comment: @Wiz, yes, it'll return zero or hang until it's finished, the example code on MSDN does use checking for zero though.